# Curl and relative path in <head>

Tags: php, curl, relative-path

Im ising this script to scrape a website:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.nu.nl";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

The output ads the wrong domain in javascript,css files in the head section. So I tried to fix it with:

```
$url = preg_replace("/<head>/i", "<head><base href='$url' />", $url, 1);
```

Doesn't work, any ideas why? I can't spot anything.

[Example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wyj-g5a)

Comment: The variable `$url` is misleading. It is a string that contains HTML, so `$html` or `$html_output` would be a better name.

Comment: adding a base tag like that isn't going to affect urls in css `url()` directives and whatnot.

Comment: @ Frits van Campen I understand what you are saying, but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @Marc B I added a base tag before with javascript, I was trying to do it server side. But now you are saying that wouldn't work. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the right variables? `$curl_scraped_page` is your page and `$url` your url... But you passed `$url` to `preg_replace`.

```
$curl_scraped_page = preg_replace("/<head>/i", "<head><base href='$url' />", $curl_scraped_page, 1);
```

Comment: @Youss did you replace also the `$url` at the end of your function call by `$curl_scraped_page`?

Comment: It works! I must have did something wrong before..Thank you very much:-)