# cURL PHP Domain Defaults to Localhost

Tags: php, curl, https, http-status-code-404

I am requesting a site with cURL that atomatically logs in and although everything works perfectly every `GET` request after the script logs in will contain "localhost" in the URL instead of the actual domain of the site so it throws a `404` not found error.

Example: Instead of being https://remotesite.com/dashboard it does http://localhost.com/dashboard *(Also notice it is not using https for http://localhost.com/dashboard)*

**Here is my code:**

```
$curl = curl_init();

$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';
$url = 'https://remotesite.com/dashboard';
$post_data = 'username=username&password=password&cookie=true&destination=&login=Log+In';

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
$errmsg  = curl_error($curl);

echo $result;
```

Comment: If it's a post request you should set `CURLOPT_POST` to `TRUE`. Depending on your PHP version it might be `FALSE` by default. See if that has any effect.

Comment: @Max tried it but didn't work :(

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Max no idea, I am using the network at work.

Comment: are you on Linux or Windows? it might be since you are using an office internet connection

Comment: @Max I am using Windows.

Comment: And can you find out if you are behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the site you are trying to access uses relatives paths in its hrefs.
So you should try changing the [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to use the correct domain.

This question might help you: [Curl and relative path in <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065036/curl-and-relative-path-in-head) .